# getting only one record from the database in laravel

Tags: laravel

I don't know how to get just one record from the database. I'm doing it with foreach, as if it were several records. How can i get just one record?
this is my code:

```
$usuario = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM usuarios where id=:id',['id' => session('id')]);
          foreach ($usuario as $u)
            {
                $nombre=$u->nombre;
                $email=$u->email;
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you use SQL LIMIT

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @lagbox, you are using the select function which will return an array.

So in order to get the first element, you would do:

```
$usuarios = \DB::select('SELECT * FROM usuarios where id=:id',['id' => session('id')])->get();
if(!empty($usuarios)) {
    $usuario = $usuarios[0];
}
```

But you'd probably be better using the query builder, like this:

```
$usuario = \DB::table('usuarios')->where('id', session('id'))->first();
// $nombre = $usuario->nombre;
// $email = $usuario->email;
```

Comment: that isn't query builder ... `select` returns an array

Comment: though using query builder could be a better option for the OP

Comment: and since it is not the query builder, is my code vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: No, your code as shown uses the correct technique to prevent sql injections. The main advantages of using the Query builder is 1) it makes easier to swap database engines down the road by adding a layer of abstraction and 2) when you use Models in Laravel, you;'ll already be familiar with the query builder's syntax